# Which manifolds books can help me with my class?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation

[Problem Set I](http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/courses/mod/resource/view.php?id=5988)

I'm looking for books that help me understand and solve these problems. The textbook that professor suggested is really deficient. Does anyone know any books on manifolds that cover these subjects?

Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds is one adopted in the course.

Comment: Which book did the professor suggest and what do you not like about it? There is a nice book my John M. Lee. It is called "Introduction to smooth manifolds".

Comment: @PhoemueX Though yusuf should add it to the body of the question, it appears to Spivak's.

Comment: The professor suggested the calculus on manifolds from spivak. But I could not find the topics that are related with these questions in the book.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into $\mathit{Calculus\ on\ Manifolds}$ by Michael Spivak. Another book you can look at is $\mathit{An\ Introduction\ to\ Differentiable\ Manifolds\ and\ Riemannian\ Geometry}$ by William Boothby

Comment: I'd consider Spivak's book a bit over the top. Personally I'd recommend The book by Loring W. Tu "An Introduction to Manifolds" as well as the notes on "Manifolds and Differential Forms" by Reyer Sjamaar

Comment: @Nox Actually, with a little research, it appears Spivak's book is the one adopted in the course.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes Spivak's book is the one adopted but the order of topics in the class is a bit confusing. Therefore, I could not follow course content from that book. And thanks for advice.